# Owl Carousel div Height for image hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel-2

I'm trying to hover `img` inside Owl Carousel `div`. I've added simple CSS `transition` for Owl Carousel container `div`, but automatically, Owl Carousel has standard height for it. You'll see in pictures.
I've added simple border color for see `div` height.

Here is before hover:

[image: Here is before hover]
And here is when hover
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" align="center" style="border: 1px solid red;">
    <div class="item img-thumbnail grow">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x250">
            <div class="text-warning" align="center">Deneme1</div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item img-thumbnail grow">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x250">
            <div class="text-warning" align="center">Deneme2</div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

My CSS code is:

```
.grow { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
.grow:hover { transform: scale(1.1); }
```

How can I change this 'edges' for transition?
Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want exactly. Can you make your question clearer please?

Comment: When i hoover , edges of red lines is blocking my css transition. In second picture you can see my transition code blocked by div.

Comment: Did you try .grow:hover { transform: scale(1.1); z-index:1000; } or .grow { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; z-index:1000; } ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood you can solve this problem with adding one rule css,

```
.owl-stage-outer {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

[There is example](https://jsfiddle.net/elvinmammadoff/bqrLkdsc/)